# phonegap android keeps crashing for no clear reason

Tags: android, cordova, crash

My phonegap android app keeps crashing, without any apparent reason.. I can be in the process of uploading an image, or just browsing through, or even in the first login screen, and wait a bit --> and it crashes.

I have installed on my galaxy s3 (android 4.1.2) an app called "logcat", and this is what it logged:

```
03-02 18:31:38.706 I/DEBUG   (24622): pid: 14927, tid: 18457, name: AsyncTask #4  >>> me.remini.example <<<
03-02 18:31:48.176 I/ActivityManager(2273): Process me.remini.example (pid 14927) (adj 0) has died.
```

What can I do?